# Can't access external storage when uploading file

Tags: android, image, ftp

I want to make file uploading to ftp. I'm using this code. But everytime I try to take image from the storage, it always trow me exception failed to choose file. This happene after i upgrade my android studio from android studio 1.5 to the newest. I had downgrade the gradle build too, but this isn't solve the problem. Can you tell me why is this happened?

Manifest.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.amobi.newlomapodfix">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Article"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ShopActivity"
            android:label="Shop"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ReadArtikelActivity"
            android:label="Article" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:label="Register" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="Login" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AccountActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_account"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".EditAccountActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".UploadActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CartActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".DetilBarangActivity"></activity>
        <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
             App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

UploadActivity.java

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.amobi.newlomapodfix.util.SessionManagement;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.jibble.simpleftp.SimpleFTP;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class UploadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String URL_ID_TRANS = "http://amobipets.azurewebsites.net/getIdImage.php";
    private static final String URL_INSERT_IMAGE = "http://amobipets.azurewebsites.net/insertImage.php";
    private static final String URL_EDIT_TRANS = "http://amobipets.azurewebsites.net/editTrans.php";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE_NAME = "image_name";
    private static final String TAG_STATUS = "Status";
    private static final String TAG_PESAN = "message";
    private static final String TAG_HASIL = "result";
    private static final String TAG_TRANS = "message";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE_ID = "id_image";
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jparser = new JSONParser();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> namelist, idList, imageList;
    JSONArray names, names1, names2;

    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
    String imgDecodableString = null;
    Button btn;


    static final String FTP_HOST = "************";
    static final String FTP_USER = "************";
    static final String FTP_PASS = "************";
    String name, vid;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client2;
    SessionManagement sessionManagement;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        sessionManagement =new SessionManagement(this);
        idList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        imageList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        Bundle bun = getIntent().getExtras();
        vid = bun.getString("id");

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUploadPicture);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (imgDecodableString == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Choose image first, please", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                } else {
                    File f = new File(imgDecodableString);
                    name = f.getName();
                    uploadFile(f);
                }
            }
        });

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client2 = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }


    public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
        // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // Start the Intent
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data


                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filename = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                File f = new File("" + imgDecodableString);
                f.getName();
                ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
                imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Pilih Bukti Transaksi",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to Choose", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    public void uploadFile(File fileName) {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        SimpleFTP ftp=new SimpleFTP();

        try {
            ftp.connect(FTP_HOST, 21, FTP_USER, FTP_PASS);
            ftp.bin();
            ftp.cwd("/img/");
            ftp.stor(fileName);
            ftp.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                ftp.disconnect();
                Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "disconnect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client2.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Upload Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.amobi.newlomapodfix/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client2, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Upload Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.amobi.newlomapodfix/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client2, viewAction);
        client2.disconnect();
    }

    /*******
     * Used to file upload and show progress
     **********/

  /*  public class MyTransferListener implements FTPDataTransferListener {

        public void started() {

            btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // Transfer started
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " Upload Started ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        public void transferred(int length) {

            // Yet other length bytes has been transferred since the last time this
            // method was called
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " transferred ..." + length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void completed() {

            btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // Transfer completed

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " completed ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            new InsertImage(name).execute();

        }

        public void aborted() {

            btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // Transfer aborted
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " transfer aborted , please try again...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void failed() {

            btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // Transfer failed
            System.out.println(" failed ...");
        }
    }
*/
    class InsertImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        int sukses = 0;
        String img;

        public InsertImage(String img) {
            this.img = img;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image_name", img));
            try {
                JSONObject json = jparser.makeHttpRequest(URL_INSERT_IMAGE, "GET", params);

                if (json != null) {
                    sukses = json.getInt(TAG_PESAN);

                    if (sukses == 1) {
                        namelist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                        Log.d("Semua Nama: ", json.toString());
                        names = json.getJSONArray(TAG_HASIL);

                        for (int i = 0; i < names.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = names.getJSONObject(i);
                            String img = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE_NAME);
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            map.put(TAG_IMAGE_NAME, img);

                            namelist.add(map);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            if (sukses == 1) {
                new getID().execute();
            }
        }
    }

    public class getID extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        int sukses = 0;

        public getID() {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UploadActivity.this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading . . .");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            try {
                JSONObject json = jparser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ID_TRANS, "GET", params);
                if (json != null) {
                    sukses = json.getInt(TAG_PESAN);
                    if (sukses == 1) {
                        idList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                        Log.d("Semua Nama: ", json.toString());
                        names1 = json.getJSONArray(TAG_HASIL);

                        for (int i = 0; i < names1.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = names1.getJSONObject(i);
                            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);

                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                            idList.add(map);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            String id_image;
            if(idList.size()==0)
            {
                id_image="1";
            }
            else {id_image = idList.get(0).get(TAG_ID);}
            new editTrans(id_image, "Uploaded", vid).execute();
        }
    }

    class editTrans extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        int sukses = 0;
        String id_image, status, id_trans;

        public editTrans(String id_image, String status, String id_trans) {
            this.id_image = id_image;
            this.status = status;
            this.id_trans = id_trans;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_image", id_image));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Status", status));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_trans", id_trans));

            try {
                JSONObject json = jparser.makeHttpRequest(URL_EDIT_TRANS, "GET", params);

                if (json != null) {
                    sukses = json.getInt(TAG_PESAN);

                    if (sukses == 1) {
                        imageList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                        Log.d("Semua Nama: ", json.toString());
                        names2 = json.getJSONArray(TAG_HASIL);

                        for (int i = 0; i < names2.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = names2.getJSONObject(i);
                            String stat = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);
                            String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE_ID);
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            map.put(TAG_IMAGE_ID, image);
                            map.put(TAG_STATUS, stat);

                            imageList.add(map);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            if (sukses == 1) {
                Intent i = new Intent(UploadActivity.this, AccountActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            case R.id.logout:
                sessionManagement.logoutUser();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Build.gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.amobi.newlomapodfix"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':captcha')
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
    compile files('libs/simpleftp.jar')
}
```

Comment: "it always trow me exception failed to choose file" -- if you are going to ask questions about an exception, post the entire Java stack trace for the exception. Beyond that, please note that your `onActivityResult()` code will be unreliable. There is no requirement that the image that the user picks be on the filesystem somewhere that you can access it. For example, it might be on removable storage. Please [use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html).

Comment: You are targeting API 23 Have you get runtime permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting API 23 Have to you get runtime permissions below

```
      private static final int REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION = 1;
      // Global Variable

       void checkPremission() {
            //select which permission you want
            final String permission = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
                // if in fragment use getActivity()
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ActivityName.this, permission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ActivityName.this, permission)) {

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityName.this, new String[]{permission}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                }
            } else {
                // you have permission go ahead
                // get access to storage
            } 
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION:
                    final int numOfRequest = grantResults.length;
                    final boolean isGranted = numOfRequest == 1
                            && PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == grantResults[numOfRequest - 1];
                    if (isGranted) {
                        // you have permission go ahead
                        // get access to storage

                    }else{
                        // you dont have permission show toast
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: where should i put it?

Comment: where  you are getting access to storage